# My data from db keep on loading when implemented tab in html

Tags: php, html, forms

> I need to some maintenance to the page so I implemented the tab inside the html, however this make the page keep reloading because of the php code. I already try alot of method to make php code run perfectly but they keep reloading when I insert it.

```
    <?php 

        foreach($data as $row){
            $_SESSION['custID']=$row['custID'];


    ?>

        <form action="" method="POST">
                <!----------Togglable Vertical Tabs Code Here------------>
                <div class="tab">
                <button class="tablinks" onclick="openType(event, 'Details')"id="defaultOpen">User Details</button>
                <button class="tablinks" onclick="openType(event, 'Address')">Address</button>
                <button class="tablinks" onclick="openType(event, 'Reset')">Change Password</button>
                </div>

                <div id="Details" class="tabcontent">
                    <p>Username:&emsp;</p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="custusername" value="<?=$row['custusername']?>" readonly></p>

                    <p>Phone Number:&emsp;&emsp;</p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="custhpnumber" value="<?=$row['custhpnumber']?>" required></p>


                    <p>Email:</p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="custemail" value="<?=$row['custemail']?>" required></p>
                </div>

                <div id="Address" class="tabcontent">
                    <p>Delivery Line 1:</p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="custaddress1" value="<?=$row['custaddress1']?>" required></p>


                    <p>Delivery Line 2:</p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="custaddress2" value="<?=$row['custaddress2']?>" required></p>

                    <p>Delivery Line 3:</p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="custaddress3" value="<?=$row['custaddress3']?>" required></p>


                    <p>Delivery Line 4:</p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="custaddress4" value="<?=$row['custaddress4']?>" required></p>

                </div>

                <!----------Change Password Content----------->
                <div id="Reset" class="tabcontent">
                    <p>Current Password:</p>
                    <p><input type="password" name="custpassword" id="myInput1" value="<?=$row['custpassword']?>" required></p>

                    <p>New Password:</p>
                    <p><input type="password" name="custpassword" id="myInput2" value="<?=$row['custpassword']?>" required></p>

                    <p>Confirm New Password:</p>
                    <p><input type="password" name="custpassword" id="myInput3" value="<?=$row['custpassword']?>" required></p>
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Show Password

                <!----------Show Password JS Here----------->
                <script src="Script/pass.js"></script>

                </div>

                
                <!----------Togglable Vertical Tabs JS Here------------>
                <script src="Script/tab.js"></script>

                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right;">
                    <br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete">Delete Profile</button>&emsp;
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update">Update Profile</button>
                    </br>
                    </td>
                    </center>
                    
            <?php 
        } ?>             
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is the Controller for the page:

```
<?php
```

require_once '../../BusinessLayer/model/manageUserProfileModel.php';

class manageUserProfileController{

```
function viewCust($custID){
    $user = new manageUserProfileModel();
    $user->custID = $custID;
    return $user->viewCustomer();
}

function updateCust(){
    $user = new manageUserProfileModel();
    $user->custID = $_SESSION['custID'];
    $user->custusername = $_POST['custusername'];
    $user->custhpnumber = $_POST['custhpnumber'];
    $user->custemail = $_POST['custemail'];
    $user->custaddress1 = $_POST['custaddress1'];
    $user->custaddress2 = $_POST['custaddress2'];
    $user->custaddress3 = $_POST['custaddress3'];
    $user->custaddress4 = $_POST['custaddress4'];
    if($user->updateCustomer()){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your profile are success Update!!!');
        window.location = './customerProfile.php?custID=".$_SESSION['custID']."';</script>";     
    }
    else
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your profile are failed Update!!!');
        window.location = './customerProfile.php?custID=".$_SESSION['custID']."';</script>";
}

function deleteCust($custID){
    $user = new manageUserProfileModel();
    $user->custID = $custID;
    if($user->deleteCustomer()){
        $message = "Success Delete!";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');
        window.location = '../../ApplicationLayer/manageLoginAndRegister/userLogin.php';</script>";
    }
}

function viewSP($spID){
    $user = new manageUserProfileModel();
    $user->spID = $spID;
    return $user->viewServiceProvider();
}

function updateSP(){
    $user = new manageUserProfileModel();
    $user->spID = $_SESSION['spID'];
    $user->spusername = $_POST['spusername'];
    $user->sphpnumber = $_POST['sphpnumber'];
    $user->spemail = $_POST['spemail'];
    $user->spcompanyname = $_POST['spcompanyname'];
    $user->spaddress1 = $_POST['spaddress1'];
    $user->spaddress2 = $_POST['spaddress2'];
    $user->spaddress3 = $_POST['spaddress3'];
    $user->spaddress4 = $_POST['spaddress4'];
    $user->spbanktype = $_POST['spbanktype'];
    $user->spbankaccountnumber = $_POST['spbankaccountnumber'];
    if($user->updateServiceProvider()){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your profile are success Update!!!');
        window.location = './serviceproviderProfile.php?spID=".$_SESSION['spID']."';</script>";
    }
    else
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your profile are failed Update!!!');
        window.location = './serviceproviderProfile.php?spID=".$_SESSION['spID']."';</script>";
}

function deleteSP($spID){
    $user = new manageUserProfileModel();
    $user->spID = $spID;
    if($user->deleteServiceProvider()){
        $message = "Success Delete!";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');
        window.location = '../../ApplicationLayer/manageLoginAndRegister/userLogin.php';</script>";
    }
}

function viewRun($runnerID){
    $user = new manageUserProfileModel();
    $user->runnerID = $runnerID;
    return $user->viewRunner();
}

function updateRun(){
    $user = new manageUserProfileModel();
    $user->runnerID = $_SESSION['runnerID'];
    $user->runnerusername = $_POST['runnerusername'];
    $user->runnerhpnumber = $_POST['runnerhpnumber'];
    $user->runneremail = $_POST['runneremail'];
    $user->runnervehiclemodel = $_POST['runnervehiclemodel'];
    $user->runnervehicleplatenumber = $_POST['runnervehicleplatenumber'];
    $user->runnercity = $_POST['runnercity'];
    $user->runnerbanktype = $_POST['runnerbanktype'];
    $user->runnerbankaccountnumber = $_POST['runnerbankaccountnumber'];
    if($user->updateRunner()){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your profile are success Update!!!');
        window.location = './runnerProfile.php?runnerID=".$_SESSION['runnerID']."';</script>";
    }
    else
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your profile are failed Update!!!');
        window.location = './runnerProfile.php?runnerID=".$_SESSION['runnerID']."';</script>";
}

function deleteRun($runnerID){
    $user = new manageUserProfileModel();
    $user->runnerID = $runnerID;
    if($user->deleteRunner()){
        $message = "Success Delete!";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');
        window.location = '../../ApplicationLayer/manageLoginAndRegister/userLogin.php';</script>";
    }
}
```

}
?>

Comment: Your code isn't very well formatted - try having a look at [post formatting tips](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Your post has a lot of code to description ratio, so adding some more context as to what you've tried and what you're hoping to happen.

In the HTML file, your braces aren't balanced by the look of it (the foreach loop starts before the <form> tag, but ends after the closing form tag). If I could offer one piece of advice in coding is to watch your indentation, as that will save a lot of headaches.

Comment: The foreach loop was inside the <form> tag at first but the problem is still persistent. I thought maybe putting them before would resolve the problem at 1st